# PHP: Parse unnamed arguments from url

Tags: php

I'm truing to parse arguments like `http://localhost/img/
module/border.php?type,colorScheme,template`.
How to parse it by `$_GET`?

`print_r($_GET);` outputs `Array ( [type,colorScheme,template] => )`

Comment: echo explode('?',"http://localhost/img/module/border.php?type,colorScheme,template")[1]

Comment: *"outputs `Array ( [type,colorScheme,template] => )`"* ... well, yes ... that's what you've sent - what were you expecting?

Comment: I just did not know about `key()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
$args = explode(",", key($_GET));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` , it contains the data that you are looking for.
After that, just explode this like `explode(',',$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])`.

*OUTPUT*

```
Array
(
    [0] => type
    [1] => colorScheme
    [2] => template
)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you wrote in `$_GET` is 1 variable.
To separate multiple `$_GET` variables, use `&`.

```
http://localhost/img/module/border.php?type&colorScheme&template
```

To assign values write

```
?type=sometype&colorScheme=somecolor&template=sometemplate
```

If you really need/want to send 1 `$_GET`variable as you wrote, use `explode()` which need the delimiter and the string to split:

```
explode(",", key($_GET));
```

[PHP.net - explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)
[PHP.net - key](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php)